# Error when creating a static field

Tags: java, static

I created a static field `c` on my class but it generated an error saying `illegal start of expression`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("program started.");    
    static Controller c; //Where the error is

    try {
        Model m = new Model();
        View v = new View();
        c = new Controller(m,v);
        c.sendDataToView();
        c.showView();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a `static` field (or any other field, for that matter) inside a method, even if it is a `static` one.

You can either declare a `static` field outside the method:

```
static Controller c;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("program started.");

    try {
       Model m = new Model();
       View v = new View();
       c = new Controller(m,v);
       c.sendDataToView();
       c.showView();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Or a plain old fashioned local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("program started.");

    Controller c;
    try {
       Model m = new Model();
       View v = new View();
       c = new Controller(m,v);
       c.sendDataToView();
       c.showView();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why declaring a field inside a method is not allowed?

Comment: @Francisco that's just not how java works - fields are members of a **class**, so they should be declared under the class - a variable inside a method is local to that method, and thus doesn't need (and can't have) access modifiers, excepts for `final`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a static field inside a method.

Move it outside :

```
static Controller c;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("program started.");
    try {
        Model m = new Model();
        View v = new View();
        c = new Controller(m,v);
        c.sendDataToView();
        c.showView();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```